Saving a Collection within a Table PowerApps
I'm building an app on PowerApps, its a form that is normally completed on paper.
I've built the app and have the functionality of it working within the canvas but trying to save the collected information to a table.
This is the "basic" information that is only collected once per form.

This is the bulk of the information, that is essentially a table itself. It's currently set up as a collection and working fine. The name of the collection is "DipRecord".

I'm trying to save all of this to a table in my environment called "Dipping Record Table".
Ideally, for each completion of my form, I would like a single row to my table. In order for this to happen, the entire collection would need to be saved in a single column in my table (so the table variable gets saved with a column called "DipRecords").
Is this possible?
If so, how do I save the collection within that column and how do I set up the column within the table? (as there is no obvious way to assign a table variable to a column when creating the table).
Or would I need to create a separate table specifically for the "DipRecord" collection and create a one-to-many relationship between a table that collects the project/dip details and the table that stores the collection?
Thanks in advance.

I would put all these numbers into a JSON-formatted object and into a long text type fielde: Like:
{
    "1500": [
        {
            "dips01": "420",
            "dips02": "",
            "dips03": "410",
            "dips04": "",
            "dips05": ""
        }
    ],
    "1510": [
        {
            "dips01": "415",
            "dips02": "420",
            "dips03": "425",
            "dips04": "430",
            "dips05": "435"
        }
    ]
}

